# Creating multiple subsets of a timeseries pandas dataframe by weekly intervals

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

New to python. I have a dataframe with a date time column (essentially a huge time series data). I basically want to divide this into multiple subsets where each subset data frame contains one week worth of data (starting from the first timestamp). I have been trying this with groupBy and Grouper but it returns tuples which themselves don't contain a week's worth of data. In addition, the Grouper (Erstwhile TimeGrouper) documentation isn't very clear on this.

This is what I tried. Any better ideas or approaches?

```html
grouped = uema_label_format.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='HEADER_START_TIME', freq='W'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your dataset is really big, it could be worth externalising this work to a time-series database and then query it to get each week you are interested in. These results can then be loaded into pandas, but the database handles the heavy lifting. For example in QuestDB you could get the current week as follows

```
select * from yourTable where timestamp = '2020-06-22;7d'
```

Although this would return the data for a single week, you could iterate on this to get the individual objects quickly since the results are instantaneous. Also, you can easily change the sample interval after the fact, for example to monthly using `1M`. This would still be an instant response.

You can try this [here](http://try.questdb.io:9000/index.html) using this query as an example to get one week worth of data (roughly 3M rows) out of a 1.6 billion rows NYC taxi dataset.

```
select * from trips where pickup_datetime = '2015-08-01;7d';
```

If this would solve your use case, there is a tutorial on how to get query results from QuestDB to pandas [here](https://dev.to/davidgs/questdb-with-python-291j).